# Trying to create a template with subsites

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-template

I'm trying to create a template that I'm going to need to replicate several times.  Unfortunately there are sub-sites beneath the main site on the template that are complicating things. From what I can tell it's not possible to save subsites inside of templates.

Is there an easy way to do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible using PowerShell. First, create site templates for the sub-sites. Then use the [New-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579(v=office.14).aspx) cmdlet to create the parent, then the sub-sites from the templates. Keep in mind [you must use the GUID](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2554dc20-cbbb-469e-bbc7-af181ed18f50/create-sites-with-powershell-script-using-saved-templates?forum=sharepointadminprevious) of the template.

Keep in mind that site templates are only [one of many options for provisioning new sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx). The new [WebTemplate method in 2010](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/06/15/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

From my understanding of the question, the author wants to know if we can save a site template containing it's subsites.

There are many workarounds ([backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901%28v=office.15%29.aspx), [export](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/0dce442c-496f-4953-a629-68b940facde3/exporting-sites-and-its-subsites), individual templates), and I believe Tom has layed down some very good approach(es).

However, site templates are saved independently for each site (web), and not even PowerShell can overcome that, hence, my different answer.

As usual, some references:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f167d3ac-afd4-407c-8108-2ae896d52752/how-to-save-site-template-with-subsites?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

[Move root site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109732/move-root-site-collection)

Anyway, I won't feel terribly disappointed if this answer is not selected.